# Spark How can I filter out rows that contain char sequences from another dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

So, I am trying to remove rows from df2 if the Value in df2 is "like" a key from df1.  I'm not sure if this is possible, or if I might need to change df1 into a list first? It's a fairly small dataframe, but as you can see, we want to remove the 2nd and 3rd rows from df2 and just return back df2 without them.

```
df1
+--------------------+
|                 key|
+--------------------+
|   Monthly Beginning|
|   Annual Percentage|
+--------------------+

df2
+--------------------+--------------------------------+
|                 key|                           Value|
+--------------------+--------------------------------+
|                Date|                        1/1/2018|
|                Date|    Monthly Beginning on Tuesday|
|              Number|   Annual Percentage Rate for...|
|              Number|                            17.5|
+--------------------+--------------------------------+
```

I thought it would be something like this?

```
df.filter(($"Value" isin (keyDf.select("key") + "%"))).show(false)
```

But that doesn't work and I'm not surprised, but I think it helps show what I am trying to do if my previous explanation was not sufficient enough.  Thank you for your help ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the first `dataframe` `df1` to `List[String]` and then create one `udf` and apply `filter` condition

**Spark-shell-**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

//Converting df1 to list
val df1List=df1.select("key").map(row=>row.getString(0).toLowerCase).collect.toList

//Creating udf , spark stands for spark session

spark.udf.register("filterUDF", (str: String) => df1List.filter(str.toLowerCase.contains(_)).length)

//Applying filter
df2.filter("filterUDF(Value)=0").show

//output

+------+--------+
|   key|   Value|
+------+--------+
|  Date|1/1/2018|
|Number|    17.5|
+------+--------+
```

**Scala-IDE -**

```
val sparkSession=SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("temp").getOrCreate() 

val df1=sparkSession.read.format("csv").option("header","true").load("C:\\spark\\programs\\df1.csv")

val df2=sparkSession.read.format("csv").option("header","true").load("C:\\spark\\programs\\df2.csv")

import sparkSession.implicits._

val df1List=df1.select("key").map(row=>row.getString(0).toLowerCase).collect.toList

sparkSession.udf.register("filterUDF", (str: String) => df1List.filter(str.toLowerCase.contains(_)).length)

df2.filter("filterUDF(Value)=0").show
```

Comment: Hmm, that looks promising, but I am getting an error:  Failed to execute user defined function(anonfun$main$2: (string) => int)

Comment: Are you doing the same as I did? where you are dong in spark-shell or ide?

Comment: Yea, I pretty much copied it, I am doing this in IntelliJ IDE

Comment: Hm, it's still giving me the same error.  I wonder if there is an issue with my environment then.

Comment: yes check for that and also check that internet is working in your machine.

Comment: I figured it out, it doens't handle null values so i had to select where isNotNull.  Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Convert df1 to List. Convert df2 to Dataset.

```
case class s(key:String,Value:String)
df2Ds = df2.as[s]
```

Then we can use the filter method to filter out the records.
Somewhat like this.

```
def check(str:String):Boolean = {
var i = ""
for(i<-df1List)
{
    if(str.contains(i))
        return false
}
return true
}

df2Ds.filter(s=>check(s.Value)).collect
```

Comment: I will try it, what is s.col2 though?

Comment: case class s(key:String,value:String)
df2Ds = df2.as[s]

here..you will have to use value

Comment: @LeythG Did you try this?